# Is it possible to turn NSNonactivatingPanelMask on and off on an NSPanel

Tags: cocoa, appkit, nspanel

I understand that this use case is atypical, but I've been trying to figure out a way to make an `NSPanel` non-activating, only in some circumstances.

If an `NSPanel` is initialized with `NSNonactivatingPanelMask` (or if the "Non Activating" property of the panel is checked in Interface Builder), altering the style mask later in code has no effect on the window behavior:

```
[panel setStyleMask:([panel styleMask] | NSNonactivatingPanelMask)];
```

Inspecting the `styleMask` property shows that `NSNonactivatingPanelMask` is on, but clicking on its titlebar still activates the application.

The inverse is also true. Initializing with `NSNonactivatingPanelMask` and setting the mask to `([panel styleMask] & ~NSNonactivatingPanelMask)` later in code has no effect on the window behavior, causing it to *not* activate the application when the titlebar is clicked.

Is there a simple workaround for this, such as a way to tell the window to reinterpret its style mask? If not, what is the best suitable alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Only solution I've found is to let non-activating checkbox in IB unchecked. Then set or remove NSNonactivatingPanelMask flag later in code.

```
if (nonactivating)
    self.window.styleMask &= ~NSNonactivatingPanelMask;
else
    self.window.styleMask |= NSNonactivatingPanelMask;
```

You are still able to activate your application by clicking on window's title bar which could be undesired. Either you can disable title bar entirely or take it as another way to activate your application.